# Typescript,: '{}[]' is not assignable to type 'CustomType[]' Error on Observable

Tags: angular, typescript, nativescript, strongloop

the following propblem already took 6 hours of my day so I really hope you can help me. 
My goal right now is to retrieve a list of objects (custom typed / "Fantasy") from a mongodb via a StrongLoop API for a Nativescript app. The code for that in my app.component.ts looks like this (The Error occures in the function `getFantasies()`:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";
import { Fantasy } from "../../sdk/models/Fantasy";
import { LoopBackConfig, FantasyApi } from "../../sdk";

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: "Itemlist",
  templateUrl: "./itemlist.component.html",
  styleUrls: ["./itemlist-common.css", "./itemlist.css"],
  providers: [FantasyApi]
})

export class ItemlistComponent implements OnInit {
  private fantasies: Array<Fantasy> = new Array();

constructor(
    private fs: FantasyApi) {
    LoopBackConfig.setBaseURL('http://localhost:3000');
    LoopBackConfig.setApiVersion('api');
}

ngOnInit() {
    this.getFantasies();
}

    getFantasies(): void {
    this.fs.find()
        .subscribe(res => this.fantasies = res)
}
```

The error comes from "this.fantasies" in the second last line and says:

```
[ts]
Type '{}[]' is not assignable to type 'Fantasy[]'.
  Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Fantasy'.
[ts]
Type '{}[]' is not assignable to type 'Fantasy[]'.
  Type '{}' is not assignable to type 'Fantasy'.
    Property '"category"' is missing in type '{}'.
```

The model "Fantasy" has some non-optional properties of with "category" is the first. 
From my understanding, the by default empty return-object `{}` of that function causes a problem with the mandatory properties (that do not exists in this case) of the "Fantasy"-model.

How could I resolve that probleme?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: are you sure you get data returned?

Comment: The error occures on compiling, so the actual return should not the problem (the api works)

Comment: not sure then because the subscribe cant return that error on compile

Comment: So it's most likely a problem with the (StrongLoop-generated) API?

Comment: i believe so but without trying it, i cant say